# Type operator instead of declaring an interface that extends a class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

[According to typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#interfaces-extending-classes), interfaces can extend classes in the following way:

```
class C {
  f1: string;
  f2: number;
}

interface I extends C {};
```

Note that I didn't extend `I` with extra members and that's why the body `{}` is empty.

The difference between I and C is of course that the plain object `{ f1: "hi", f2: 3}` conforms to `I` but not to `C` (because while it has all the fields, it hasn't been produced from C's constructor)

I want to know, is there a type operator that can get `I` from `C` without having to declare `I`? e.g. something like `operator<C>` which is equivalent to `I` (you could perhaps even use `type I = operator<C>`?

Comment: Why not use `type I = C`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your intended use, you might actually be fine just using `C`. For example:

```
class C {
  constructor(public f1: string, public f2: number){}
}

interface I extends C {}

function getF1(x: C) {
   return x.f1;
}

const x: C = { f1: "abc", f2: 123 };

getF1(x); // returns "abc"
```

Note when you use `C` in a type annotation, Typescript doesn't actually ensure that the object is really an instance of `C`, but rather that it has all the properties.
What you wrote isn't really true, that the plain object doesn't "conform" to `C`. According to TS type system, it does.

If you had a more complex class and wanted for some reason to do something like get all the attributes but not the methods, you could use a TS [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) with a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that would return all the properties that are not a function.

In general, it's always worth using the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) to investigate the result of transpilation, to better realize the differences between classes and interfaces in TS.

```
const sth = { foo: 100 };
const i: I = { f1: "hi", f2: 3};
const fakeC: C = { f1: "hi", f2: 3};
const trueC = new C("h1", 3);

// does it conform to type C at transpilation time?
function ofTypeC(x: C) { return true; }
// ofTypeC(sth); // error
ofTypeC(i); // true
ofTypeC(fakeC); // true
ofTypeC(trueC); // true

// does it conform to type I at transpilation time?
function ofTypeI(x: I) { return true; }
// ofTypeI(sth); // error
ofTypeI(i); // true
ofTypeI(fakeC); // true
ofTypeI(trueC); // true

// is it an instance of class C at run time?
sth instanceof C // false
i instanceof C // false
fakeC instanceof C // false
trueC instanceof C // true
```

Or perhaps for sth more demonstrative of the caveats for using JS classes as TS types:

```
class Cat {
  public meow() {console.log("meow")}
}

class Dog {
  public meow() {console.log("Nah man")}
}

let cat: Cat = new Dog();
cat.meow();
```